# Importing a .csv file with varying name into powershell

Tags: powershell, user-interface, import-csv

Complete novice here,
Creating a basic GUI that allows me to automatically adjust a bill of materials .csv file with relatively minimal user input. Its basic function is to add a ".DXF" file extension to the end of each value in the first column - all of this functionality is working for now but I'm trying to find out how to import a csv without an explicit filename in the import-csv -path. The .csv file will always contain the word "BOM", so I've tried to allocate a $FileName that I can use with import-csv, but I think I'm using the get childitem cmdlet wrong.

UPDATE: I'm trying to find a way to search a browsed folder directory ($path), to find a BOMxx.csv file so I can assign a variable to the "xx", where xx would follow the form "_ 0", "_ 1", "_ 2" etc.  I then hope to use import-csv on the BOMxx.csv and amend the "$($*.PartName).DXF" to be "$($*.PartName)xx.DXF", so the newly exported CSV column includes "xx.DXF" on the end of each partname.

```
function Execute {
    $FileName = gci -Recurse | Where { $_.Name -match 'BOM' } | Select Fullname
    Import-Csv -Path "$path\$FileName.csv" | ForEach-Object {
        $_.PartName = "$($_.PartName).DXF" 
        $_ 
    } | Export-Csv -Path "$path\PrimeCutImport.csv" -NoTypeInformation
}

$result = $LocalBOMForm.ShowDialog()

if ($result –eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Cancel) {
    write-output 'Cancelled'
}
```

Any feedback on this would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.
EDIT:
Added $path for clarification:

```
$BrowseBtn.Add_Click( { Browse })
function Browse { 
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms") | Out-Null

    $foldername = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
    $foldername.Description = "Select a folder"
    $foldername.rootfolder = "MyComputer"
    $foldername.SelectedPath = $initialDirectory
    if ($foldername.ShowDialog() -eq "OK") {
        $folder += $foldername.SelectedPath
    }
    return $folder
}

$path = Browse
```

UPDATE 2:
Got it to work how I needed it to.
Might be a bit janky but it works:

```
function Execute {
    $rev=gci -path "$path" -Filter BOM*.csv | Select-Object -Property PSChildName 
$rev=$rev -replace "\D+"
    Import-Csv -Path "$path\BOM_$rev.csv" | ForEach-Object {
        $_.PartName = "$($_.PartName)_$rev.DXF" 
        $_ 
    } | Export-Csv -Path "$path\PrimeCutImport_$rev.csv" -NoTypeInformation
}
```

Thanks for the responses.

Comment: Seems like you need to loop over each `$FileName`, you also dont need `Select Fullname`

Comment: Also is not clear what `$path` is

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, $path is just the output of a browse folder form, I've edited the initial comment to show this. I'm not entirely sure what you mean by loop over $FileName (using foreach-object?), also, just realized the gci is not looking in the directory I have the files in ($path), just to clarify what would be the easiest way of allocating the resulting found filename from the gci to the import-csv.

Comment: `Get-ChildItem -Path '\path\to\your\files' -Recurse -Filter '*BOM*.csv' | Import-Csv | Select-Object -Property @{Name = 'PartName'; Expression = { "$($_.PartName).DXF" } } | Export-Csv -Path "$path\PrimeCutImport.csv" -NoTypeInformation`

Comment: Thanks Daniel, would there be a way of assigning a variable to the full name of the file that a gci search finds? Tried replacing the code I had with yours and it seems to be spitting out an empty .csv. I've realized my initial idea might not work so well so I've edited my initial post to better reflect the goal.